# Linq Query with Include Doesn't Appear to be Return Proper Results in EF 4.0

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0 and I'm running into a problem with the following query:

```
IQueryable<user> users = 
    from u in Entities.users.
        Include("orders_assigned").Include("orders_assigned.order_line_items")
    from o in u.orders_assigned
    where 
        o.status.Equals((int)OrderStatus.ReadyForInvestigation) &&
        o.assigned_to_user_id != 0
    from oli in o.order_line_items
    where 
        oli.line_item_type.Equals("service") ||
        oli.line_item_type.Equals("package_service")
    select u;
```

I'm trying to return a list of users containing a sub list of their orders, containing a sub list of the order line items (something like user->orders->order_line_items) as shown by the includes above - however whenever I call `ToTraceString` this query it shows only returning a list of users.

I've used `Include` before with no problems, not sure what I'm doing wrong this time.

Comment: How are you configuring the relationship in your model between `users` and `orders_assigned`?  It seems like there may be a problem there.

Comment: The relationship is defined in EF by foriegn keys - i've performed other linq queries using include that returned the proper results, for some reason this one isn't tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
IQueryable<user> users = ((ObjectQuery<user>)
    from u in Entities.users
    from o in u.orders_assigned
    where 
        o.status.Equals((int)OrderStatus.ReadyForInvestigation) &&
        o.assigned_to_user_id != 0
    from oli in o.order_line_items
    where 
        oli.line_item_type.Equals("service") ||
        oli.line_item_type.Equals("package_service")
    select u).Include("orders_assigned").Include("orders_assigned.order_line_items");
```

[Explanation here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx)